# Generating listboxitems with XML in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I’d like to find out what will be the closest approach to generate XML content in Silverlight that matches XMLDataProvider in WPF? Ideally, I want to generate the content purely in XAML. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write an Interactivity Behavior (inheriting from System.Interactivity.Behavior), which takes an xml DataSource (like an XElement dependency property), and adds ListBoxItem's to the associated ListBox.

You'd have to write the code once, but after you can attach the behavior purely in XAML.

If you need more generic approach than a simple transformation in code, you'd need to implement your own provider, see [this really detailed blog post](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/04/19/silverlight-and-xml-binding.aspx) on the subject...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link. I highly value your help.